# pillow change picture color when save the picture

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to write text the picture. with imshow picture is yellow, when i save it, it is blue. i can try change rgb but i couldn't. it is important for my nephew. (his birthday) how can i fix it?

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('atadavetlistesi.csv',encoding= 'UTF-8')
for i in df["isimler"] :

    picture = cv2.imread('atadogumgunu.png')
    pil_im = Image.fromarray(picture)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_im)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("comici.ttf", 28, encoding="UTF-8")  
    draw.text((170, 240), i, (60,60,150), font=font)      
    # cv2_text_im = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pil_im), cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    # cv2_text_im = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pil_im), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2_text_im = np.array(pil_im)
    cv2.imshow("Resim",cv2_text_im)
    saved_im=Image.fromarray(cv2_text_im)
    saved_im=saved_im.save(i+".jpg")
```

[image: added text picture]
[image: orijinal picture]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read your image from disk with **OpenCV** here:

```
picture = cv2.imread('atadogumgunu.png')
```

which will use BGR order. Then you save it with **PIL** here:

```
saved_im=saved_im.save(i+".jpg")
```

which expects RGB order - so it is bound not to work.

---

The easiest thing is to load your image with **PIL** at the start and avoid **OpenCV** altogether so just use:

```
pil_im = Image.open('atadogumgunu.png').convert('RGB')
```

Comment: thank you very much. i can't vote but you are righ. i try,
cv2_text_im = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pil_im), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
and fix it. best to do, i will use PIL when opening image, from now on.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Even if you cannot upvote, you can still accept the answer as correct by clicking the hollow ✅ near the vote count. That will also give you points and may allow you to upvote also. Good luck with your project.